# jQuery event stops working after alert

Tags: jquery, click

I have a jQuery event that works fine until an alert is called.  The function calls a script on the the server that adds an item (inserts a row in the database) to the cart.  Only eight items are allowed in the cart, so when the user tries to add the ninth item, a message is returned to the jQuery script that that is not allowed.  Here is the jQuery script:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'a.add.module, a.remove.module', function(e) {

    if (blnProcessing == true) {
        return false;
    } else {
        blnProcessing = true;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    objLink = jQuery(this);
    strLink = objLink.attr('href');

    if (objLink.hasClass('add')) {
        objLink.text('Adding');
    } else {
        objLink.text('Wait');
    }

    jQuery.get(strLink, function(data) {
        if (data.success) {
            if (data.success != true) {
                alert(data.success);  // message that says this is not allowed -- this part stops the script from functioning further
            } else {
                // this part works
                jQuery('#cart').load('/study-clubs/modules/cart', function(){
                    if (objLink.hasClass('add')) {
                        strNewLink = strLink.replace('add', 'remove');
                        objLink.attr('href', strNewLink);
                        objLink.removeClass('add').addClass('remove').text('Added');
                    } else if (objLink.hasClass('remove')) {
                        strNewLink = strLink.replace('remove', 'add');
                        objLink.attr('href', strNewLink);
                            objLink.removeClass('remove').addClass('add').text('Add');
                    }

                    blnProcessing = false;

                });
            }
        } else {
            alert(data.error);
            blnProcessing = false;
        }
    }, 'json');
});
```

Ordinarily, with this kind of behavior, you use `$(document).on('click', '#someID', function() ...`.  But I'm already using that.  So do I need to reattach the event listener or something.  How do I get this to work after the alert?

Comment: What code do you expect to run after the alert?

Comment: don't you need to parse the response since you're using `$.get()`?

Comment: I expect this event to fire again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `data.success` contains a value that evaluates to true in a boolean context but does not equal `true` (ergo the block containing `alert(data.success)` is executed), your `blnProcessing` flag is never reset.

FWIW, I realize it sometimes takes an extra pair of eyes, but you really should have been able to figure this out by stepping through your code in Firebug (or another set of developer tools).

Comment: The thing is, after the initial message back from the server, I never get any messages back in Firebug.  The add links just stop working.  I can't even console.log(data).

Comment: Above data.success call, I mean.   I know how to use Firebug.  There's no need to be rude.

Comment: I apologize if I came across as rude, that was not my intention. If you put a breakpoint inside your click handler though you should see it step into the first if statement and return false.

Comment: If I put a console.log above the get call, it fires until the alert is called.  It's like the event handler is getting detached.  All links with the add class stop working.  I can't console.log anything after the alert is called.

Comment: @sehummel I'm saying **it doesn't get that far**. Put a breakpoint at the **very first line**.

Comment: My apologies.  Thank you.